# Nginx Configuration to bind a range of ports to 80 and set proxy_pass to a number route

Tags: nginx, port, reverse-proxy

I can only run traffic through port 80 on my server.

What I am looking to do:

- port 8080 to bind to /8080
- port 8081 to bind to /8081
- and so on

Can I do this be done programatically in the conf file or do I need to time-consumingly set a location configuration for each of the individual ports?

Comment: I think this is your answer: https://serverfault.com/a/318006/505063

Comment: @ofirule I can work with that. Thanks!